# How to iterate through listview cells C#

Tags: c#, listview

I have a ListView that starts with a variable number of columns, and an array list of items that I insert into it using the following:

```
for (int x = 0; x < arrayList.Count; x++)
            {
                        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("IF");
                        item.SubItems.Add("ID");
                        item.SubItems.Add("EX");
                        item.SubItems.Add("MEM");
                        item.SubItems.Add("WB");
                        for (int k = 5; k < ccNum; k++)//Set rest of row cells ""
                            item.SubItems.Add("");
                        listView5.Items.Add(item);
            }
```

I want to that with every iteration the next row be shifted to the right x+1 empty values. But I can't seem to get it work, I would have to add conditional statements and enter them manually which is impractical considering the arraylist is not static:

```
                  if (x == 1)
                    {
                        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("IF");
                        item.SubItems.Add("ID");
                        item.SubItems.Add("EX");
                        item.SubItems.Add("MEM");
                        item.SubItems.Add("WB");
                        for (int k = 5; k < ccNum; k++)
                            item.SubItems.Add("");
                        listView5.Items.Add(item);
                    }
                    else if(x==2)
                    {
                        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("");
                        item.SubItems.Add("IF");
                        item.SubItems.Add("ID");
                        item.SubItems.Add("EX");
                        item.SubItems.Add("MEM");
                        item.SubItems.Add("WB");
                        for (int k = 5; k < ccNum; k++)
                            item.SubItems.Add("");
                        listView5.Items.Add(item);
                    }
                    else if(x==3)
                    {
                        ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("");
                        item.SubItems.Add("");
                        item.SubItems.Add("IF");
                        item.SubItems.Add("ID");
                        item.SubItems.Add("EX");
                        item.SubItems.Add("MEM");
                        item.SubItems.Add("WB");
                        for (int k = 5; k < ccNum; k++)
                            item.SubItems.Add("");
                        listView5.Items.Add(item);
                    } ..etc
```

If I try to access the next row cell and set it like the following:

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem("IF");
                        item.SubItems.Add("ID");
                        item.SubItems.Add("EX");
                        item.SubItems.Add("MEM");
                        item.SubItems.Add("WB");
                        for (int k = 5; k < ccNum; k++)
                            item.SubItems.Add("");
                        listView5.Items.Add(item);

                        listView5.Items[x + 1].SubItems[x].Text = "";
```

I get a runtime error:

> InvalidArgument=Value of '2' is not valid for 'index'.

Is there an easier method to implement it with ListView control or any other method for that matter?

Comment: Is that supposed to be `if (x==7)` or should the `7` be a `3`?

Comment: Yes, it should be 3. I made a mistake.

Comment: You have __such a nice loop__ adding empty subitems at the end or your main loop. __Why__ don't you insert a similar loop at the beginning?? - The other question makes no sense. What is x? where does this happen??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you can achieve this with another loop that adds the empty sub-items:

```
for (int x = 0; x < arrayList.Count; x++)
{
    //if x is 0 it's the first iteration so we want "IF"; otherwise we want ""
    ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(x == 0 ? "IF" : "");
    //add the rest of the empty sub-elements with a loop
    for (int y = 1; y < x; y++)
    {
        item.SubItems.Add("");
    }
    item.SubItems.Add("ID");
    item.SubItems.Add("EX");
    item.SubItems.Add("MEM");
    item.SubItems.Add("WB");
    for (int k = 5; k < ccNum; k++)//Set rest of row cells ""
        item.SubItems.Add("");
    listView5.Items.Add(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running into a very common array bounds issue.  let me show you a code example to help...

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var tempList = new List<string>();
        tempList.Add("1");
        tempList.Add("2");
        int x;
        for (x = 0; x < tempList.Count; x++)
        {
            //do something here
        }

        //value of x after loop
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        //the value of x is 2.

        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tempList[x]); //lets try to read the value here
        }catch(Exception e){
            Console.WriteLine("nope, not happening");
        }

        //to drive this point further home... let me show you what you did...
        tempList.Add("random");
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine(tempList[x+1]); //lets try to read the value here after we added an element
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("nope, not happening");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```